# Python.Net cannot import dll

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, python.net

I am using python 2.7 to control a [`Newport 1936-R`](https://www.newport.com/p/1936-R) power meter which uses custom `.dll`.

It is not VISA (Virtual Instrument Software Architecture) compatible so I can't use `pyvisa`.

I have installed the USB driver which contains the dll named `usbdll.dll`. I copied the dll to a system folder so that it is visible. When using Python.Net I can `AddReference` but when I import the dll I get the error `No module named usbdll`.

My Python.Net version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The correct dll to use is `UsbDllWrap.dll` located in `Samples` folder of your installation

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful, I was using another .dll but I found a work around. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around; by using NI Visa Wizard, I generated a driver and installed it. I can communicate with Newport Power Meter 1936-R with a 'raw' connection. I suggest trying NI VISA Wizard before going to Python.Net. The instrument connected can be seen in NI MAX, but not in Device Manager and pyvisa's resource manager. If anybody needs anything I am happy to help.